# Typescript can not find custom type definiton file

Tags: typescript, type-definition

I use `typescript 3.3.3` in `VS Code 1.30.2`. typescript can't find a custom type definition file which is located in `src/@types`. Although (to my knowledge) there is no need to configure `typeRoot` in the latest versions of ts but i did that also and still ts can't find `index.d.ts` file. The folder name and module name match.

```bash
.
├── config.ts
├── node_modules
├── ormconfig.json
├── package.json
├── project_manager
├── src
├── tsconfig.json
├── tslint.json
└── yarn.lock
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "target": "es2015",                       
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,                          
    "jsx": "react",                                               
    "outDir": "./dist",                       
    "strict": true,                           
    "noImplicitAny": true,                    
    "noImplicitThis": true,                   
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,                   
    "noUnusedParameters": true,               
    "moduleResolution": "node",                                       
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  
    "experimentalDecorators": true,           
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,            
    "pretty": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "project_manager",
    "dist",
    "@types"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting this working can feel like getting a magic incantation *just right*.  After some digging for a recent project, I discovered the following configuration on GitHub:

1. Set your `baseUrl` to `.`
2. Add a `paths` mapping for the directory containing your types overrides
3. Create `types-dir/module-name/index.d.ts` files for the custom types

The minimal sub-section of `tsconfig.json` would look something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./types/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

In your case, you'd probably want the `paths` to point to `./src/@types/*`.

Comment: It took me half a day to make it work and it was an act of God. i had configured `typeRoots` numerous times before and suddenly it started to work. I'm totally speechless right now. Thanks for `paths` suggestion, have seen it before but didn't do anything in my case.

Comment: Nice, glad it's working - with `paths`, that seems to go in a pair with `baseUrl`.  The two of those have to both be configured was basically the magic bit that worked for me.